# Serving a TensorFlow Custom Model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-slim

I am new in machine learning, basically i created own dataset of images and do training on them and recognize images on jupyter notebook, after this i tried to deploy this model by following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/setup) tutorial

I execute

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow_serving/example:mnist_saved_model

bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_saved_model /tmp/mnist_model
```

it runs successfully.

How to export my own model and deploy? my model name is "GoogleTensorflow"

I created this model using

```
python3 export_inference_graph.py 
--input_type image_tensor 
--pipeline_config_path training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config 
--trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-26456 
--output_directory GoogleTensorflow
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your custom training folder to tmp folder and that model should have version ex 1 folder inside it